# Where to put DllImport?

Tags: c#, dllimport

```
static class Class    
{
    public static void methodRequiringStuffFromKernel32()
    {
        // code here...
    }
}
```

Where do I put `[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]` here?

Answer (score 14):

You put it on the method you're importing from Kernel32.dll.

For example,

```
static class Class    
{
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    static extern Boolean Beep(UInt32 frequency, UInt32 duration);

    public static void methodRequiringStuffFromKernel32()
    {
        // code here...
        Beep(...);
    }
}
```

---

From @[dtb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76217/): Note that the class should be named `NativeMethods`, `SafeNativeMethods` or `UnsafeNativeMethods`. See [Naming Convention for Unmanaged Code Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btadwd4w.aspx) for more details.

[CA1060: Move P/Invokes to NativeMethods class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182161.aspx):

> - NativeMethods - This class does not suppress stack walks for unmanaged code permission. (System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute must not be applied to this class.) This class is for methods that can be used anywhere because a stack walk will be performed.
> - SafeNativeMethods - This class suppresses stack walks for unmanaged code permission. (System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute is applied to this class.) This class is for methods that are safe for anyone to call. Callers of these methods are not required to perform a full security review to make sure that the usage is secure because the methods are harmless for any caller.
> - UnsafeNativeMethods - This class suppresses stack walks for unmanaged code permission. (System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute is applied to this class.) This class is for methods that are potentially dangerous. Any caller of these methods must perform a full security review to make sure that the usage is secure because no stack walk will be performed.

Comment: Note that the class should be named `NativeMethods`, `SafeNativeMethods` or `UnsafeNativeMethods` ([Naming Convention for Unmanaged Code Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btadwd4w(v=VS.100).aspx)). The C# compiler applies some magic in this case.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What compiler magic will be applied? The link just states some naming guidelines. But no compiler magic is described. Do you have a link for further study?

Comment: @PetPaulsen: It's security-related compiler magic :-) Tbh, I don't know exactly what it does; FxCop complains when you're not doing it. I've added a quote from the FxCop documentation to the answer.

Comment: @dtb: The C# compiler does **not** apply any magic here, and it does not do so based on the name of the class. Calling it `NativeMethods` or variants is *convention only*. What gets it to apply the magic is the `System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute`, and that's done by the CLR, not the compiler.

Comment: Don't forget using `System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

Answer (score 6):

This is an example of `DllImport`:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class MsgBoxTest
{
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  static extern int MessageBox (IntPtr hWnd, string text, string caption,
                                int type);
  public static void Main()
  {
    MessageBox (IntPtr.Zero, "Please do not press this again.", "Attention", 0);
  }
}
```

I suggest you to study [Platform Invoke Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
static class Class    
{
    [DllImport("kerynel32.dll")]
    public static extern void methodRequiringStuffFromKernel32();

}
```

It goes on the method itself that's P/Invoking outside methods. Make sure to add a reference to `System.Runtime.InteropServices`