# Call a method within an imported dll outside a class where this dll was imported

Tags: c#, dll

I'm trying to call a method, which is in a dll I've imported, from another class. Is there any way to do that? Thank you in advance!
To clarify myself: There is a class called "TTSManager". In this class a dll was imported. There also is a class "TTSdotNET" and in THIS class I would like to call a method within a dll, but the method isn't accessible. I hope somebody will help me.
P.S. I code in C#
"TTSManager":
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

```
public class TTSManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
[DllImport ("SpeakerLib")]
private static extern void SpeakToSpeaker(string tts);  
[DllImport ("SpeakerLib")]
private static extern void SpeakToFile(string tts, string fileName, string fileFormat);                                     [DllImport ("SpeakerLib")]
private static extern void ReleaseSpeaker();

private static TTSManager instance = null;

private TTSManager(){}

public static TTSManager getInstance
{
    get
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new TTSManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{

}
}
```

"TTSdotNET":

```
public class TTSdotNet : MonoBehaviour 
{
 void Update () 
 {
  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F10))
  {
   SpeakToSpeaker("hello world i feel uncomfortable.");
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: hope u have referred the dll on the page where u want to call the class method?Post some code for more clarity

Comment: To clarify yourself, you might want to show some of the code that you have written that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: You would have to look at creating a method in the first class that wraps the call to the imported dll, and call that from the second class

Comment: If you want help post the code.  Otherwise we cannot help you as this question cannot be given an answer.

Comment: Considering the Law Of Demeter... Is `TTSdotNET` asking the DLL for information, or is it asking `TTSManager` for information which the DLL happens to have?

Comment: You can't import libraries(ddl) in classes, you can use namespaces. Libraries are imported in project scope. Wherever you use the namespace, you can access classes inside that specific library.

Comment: @Mert: That entirely depends on how he's interacting with the DLL.  For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076717/where-to-put-dllimport  But until he shows us any code it's all speculation.

Comment: @David, Oops, I thought of classic VS managed reference import. Sure, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to create a separate static class for the DLL imports. In addition to importing the functions I mostly also create wrapper methods for each DLL function call.

Example:

```
internal static class NativeCalls
{
    [DllImport ...]
    private static extern int SomeFunctionCall(...);

    public static int SomeFunction(...)
    {
        return SomeFunctionCall(...);
    }
}
```

That way, any class can access the DLL and your problem is solved.