# C# DllImport not found in context, but Interpor Services are bound in

Tags: c#, dllimport, interopservices

I have a problem with my compiler not being able to import kernel32.dll, althrough I'm using System.Runtime.InteropServices. Here is the Code:

```
    using System;
    ...
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace server
    {
        class Debugconsole
        {
            public void Initialise()
            {
                [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

It throws a whole bunch of syntaxerrors and "Can't find "DllImport" in current context."

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You've misplaced the `DllImport` inside a method, where it should be placed outside. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076717/where-to-put-dllimport).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes cannot be used inside a method.
You should move it out of your method:

```
class Debugconsole
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    ... the static extern method declaration ...

    public void Initialise()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you, now it works. I will give you the correct answer when it allows me to.