# Unity importing DLL causes parser error?

Tags: dll, unity-game-engine

I have a DLL which I am trying to import into my Unity project. I am following this tutorial on their website [example](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForDesktop.html). However, this line of code causes a parser error saying that "An extern alias declaration must precede all other elements."

`private static extern float FooPluginFunction ();`

I have tried searching online for the solution to this error but I do not get any results that are related to Unity. I have the DLL in my `assets/plugins` folder. Does anyone know what is causing this error and how I would fix it?

**Edit:** Script containing DLL import.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


public class VR : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

}


[DllImport ("myplugin")]
private static extern TextFunc ();
```

myplugin.dll is in my Unity `assets/plugins` folder.

Comment: @Shadowfax I have included the script where I am getting the error, it is the line directly under `[DllImport ("myplugin")]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ad30sfht.aspx) says that you have to put your dll import **above** that line where you use TextFunc() and inside a class.
**Edit**: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076717/where-to-put-dllimport).

Comment: I did not use this function. The script that I posted is the full script. I ran into the error before I could start coding the script.

Comment: Put it into your class (just above start())

Comment: Ahh thank you! This resolved the error. I'm not sure why I put it anywhere else...